# how to get 24 hour time result from convert.datetime() when evaluating a string that has time is 12 hour format

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an API that returns an event date and event time, both as string values. In addition, the time is in 12 hour format with a trailing lowercase am or pm. For example,

```
"eventTime": "6:09 pm",
"eventDate": "February 8, 2017",
```

And I am trying to save the date and time into a single datetime field in my database.

I am currently using...

```
DateTime eventDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime($"{a_item.EventDate} {a_item.EventTime}";
```

and then saving the eventDateTime value into a SQL Server 2008 R2 record field that is defined as ...

```
[EventDateTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

But when I look at the result in SQL Server, it is stored as if it was 24 hour time but ignoring the am or pm in the text that is being converted.

for example,

```
"eventTime": "6:09 pm",
"eventDate": "February 8, 2017",
```

Shows up as

```
2017-02-08 06:09:00.000
```

Instead of

```
2017-02-08 18:09:00.000
```

What do I need to do so that the date and time get saved to the database in 24 hour format so my records will sort properly?

Here is the whole method.

```
private SaveRecordResult SaveMailPieceExtractRecord(MailEvent a_item, string a_eventSource)
{
    SaveRecordResult result = new SaveRecordResult();
    result.Success = false;
    try
    {
        if (a_item != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_item.Pic))
        {
            DateTime eventDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_item.EventDate) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_item.EventTime))
            {
                eventDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime($"{a_item.EventDate} {a_item.EventTime}");  
            }

            string scanFacilityName = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_item.EventCity) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_item.EventState))
            {
                scanFacilityName = $"{a_item.EventCity}, {a_item.EventState}";
            }


            MailPieceExtracts mailPieceExtract = new MailPieceExtracts
            {
                Pic = a_item.Pic,
                ExtractFileNumber = a_item.ExtractFileNumber,
                UspsmailerName = a_item.UspsMailerName,
                UspsmailerId = a_item.UspsMailerId,
                DestinationZip = a_item.DestinationZip,
                ScanFacilityZip = a_item.EventZipCode,
                ScanFacilityName = scanFacilityName,
                EventCode = a_item.EventCode,
                EventName = a_item.Event,
                EventDateTime = eventDateTime,
                CountryCode = a_item.EventCountry,
                Recipient = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(a_item.Name)) ? a_item.Name : a_item.FirmName,
                FileReceivedDate = DateTime.Now,
                CreatedBy = a_eventSource
            };
            m_cdiMainContext.MailPieceExtracts.Add(mailPieceExtract);
            m_cdiMainContext.SaveChanges();
            result.Success = true;
            result.Error = string.Empty;
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        m_logger.LogError(2, ex, "An exception occurred while tryin to save the MailPiece_Extract record for Mail Event : [{@MailEvent}]", a_item);
        string errorMessage = $"Could not save MailPiece_Extracts record for PIC {a_item.Pic} to the database.";
        result.Error = $"{errorMessage}. The error message is [{ex.Message}]";
        return result;
    }

}
```

In the MailPieceExtracts class, the EventDateTime is just an auto property..

```
public DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: First thing, check with the debugger if the value in the variable eventDateTime is correct, if yes then the problem is in the code that stores the value on the database (missing) if it is not correct then the problem is in the conversion (tested here and it works but localization issues could affect the conversion)

Comment: @EiEiGuy, I checked the code on local machine. I used parameterized SqlCommand to store date value to db and it stored it in expected format. Can you share your version code which saves this date to the database?

Comment: The value is eventDateTime variable value is assigned to a class property of type datetime.       public DateTime EventDateTime { get; set; }  The class is a domain class that us part of a DBset in EF7. IN the Context, the DBSet modelbuilder.Entity has.. entity.Property(e => e.EventDateTime).HasColumnType("datetime");  Once I assign it to the dbset property, I call .Add(eventItem) and then SaveChanges() on the context.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the code of DbContext where the mapping of property and column is done and how are you saving the entity? That would be really helpful. I tried the use case with EF 6 with db first and code first both but could not reproduce issue. Let know if I am missing anything here...

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code. I followed the same approach as yours, configuring entity properties mapping using ModelBuilder. Only difference from your code is I am using EF6. Still I could not reproduce the issue. It saves date as expected in the db. You can try by creating a simple windows or console application and use static values for eventtime and eventdate and try to replicate the use case. May be you can find something different which is not noticeable right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Convert.ToDateTime`, use `DateTime.TryParseExact`:

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact($"{a_item.EventDate} {a_item.EventTime}", "MMMM d, yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out eventDateTime))
{
    // eventDateTime now holds correct datetime, assuming the data transfered was correct. 
}
else
{
    // Failed to parse string as datetime.
}
```

[See live example on rextester.](http://rextester.com/DEJ18810)

Comment: Good answer but this relies on the date format being consistent.

Comment: Of course, but on the other hand, nothing in the question indicated otherwise.